# How to configure appveyor to target Mono framework?

Tags: c#, github, mono, yaml, appveyor

I Try to compile a C# solution from GitHub with [appveyor](https://www.appveyor.com/), but I'm unable to target Mono Framework instead of the Microsoft .net.

This solution builds only with Mono framework >= 4.0.

Appveyor has a pre-installed Mono, but no other informations exists on the subject to target it.

What solution exists to make appveyor compile my solution with the pre-installed Mono framework?

Comment: Read how to configure Appvoyer with Mono with yml file: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/mono/appveyor.yml, I hope it may help

Comment: @M.Hassan: I've seen it but it relies on a special makefile, what command may I execute ? will xbuild be installed and callable with this script. What is the minimal makefile I should use?